# Is "words in <suffix>" correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, expressions

As I was writing an answer in another SE language forum, I used "*words in -act*" for words ending in *-act* like impact or contact.

> Words in -act are always pronounced /akt/

I said this both as a calque from French and as short for "*ending in -act*". Now I wonder, is this correct at all?

I know I can say "*words ending in*" or "*words ending with*" but it's a little heavy, is there a shorter way to say it?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"in" can mean "characterized by" so it fits in your sentence. I haven't heard of any rule that prohibits the use of "in" in this sense.

Meanings of "in":
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in (See point 1, subpoint 9)